# Android app says published but at same time says it is also "stuck" in "update pending" ! How to resolve?

Tags: android, google-play

Having a bit of a nightmare with good ole Google Play. We pushed a new release last night and the status showed as being successful and published. Now today (10+ hrs later) its clearly NOT been released in Google Play store.

To top it off, Google's Play Console app on Android (we use to check on the apps release status etc) is saying "Update Pending" AND, it resets the submitted time to the Play Store every couple of hours!!

We've lodged a "support" request to Google. But I'm hoping someone here has had same issue and there's a workaround to get this thing back on track and into the store so we don't have to wait 2 days for Google to maybe get back to us.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

hmmmm ok. so now its live. for anyone with same issue maybe this will help. i created a fresh APK (increment build#) in our CI. then I manually uploaded this new build via the Google Play Console. Same descriptions, same everything as before. A few hours later (~ 4hrs) it decided to play nice and actually DID publish to production on Google Play. Horrible deploy experience Google, you'd think after so many years this flow would be robust and reliable. Apple wins on this one atm.